# Combine gulp tasks to avoid creating the unnecessary files

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-concat, dot.js

I'm using two separate gulp tasks to minify templates into js file (1) and concat all js file of the project to the only minified (2).

```
gulp.task('templates', function() { // RESULT of this task
    return gulp.src('templates/**/*.html')
        .pipe(dotify({
            root : 'templates'
        }))
        .pipe(concat('templates.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js'));
    });


gulp.task('minifyJs', ['templates'], function() {
    return gulp.src([
        'js/templates.js',
        'js/plugins/*.js',
        'js/*.js'
    ])
    .pipe(concat('scripts-all.js'))
});
```

The question is: am I able to avoid creating the templates.js file by processing the result from first task to the second one to concat it with the rest of js's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: addSrc should be used

```
return gulp.src('templates/**/*.html')
    .pipe(dotify({
        root : 'templates'
    }))
    .pipe(addSrc([
        'js/plugins/*.js',
        'js/common/*.js',
        'js/ui/*.js',
        'js/pages/*.js',
        'js/*.js'
    ]))
    .pipe(concat('scripts-all.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('js/'));
```